# Can the chrome dev tools be on the left hand side rather then the right?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

all I was wondering if its possible to have the dev tools in chrome lock to the left side rather then the right, I know that you can simply pop the window out and put it on the left side separately but thought there would be an option to have it on the left since there is one for the right.

Is there an advance setting that I can use to switch it to the left ?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, chrome does not support docking on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docking to the left was experimented with in the past, but it was scrapped. See [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=134282).

Comment: Cheers :), not a solution but least I know why it isn't an option ha